# Typescript unselecting date on some weeks and two fridays on dec 2021

Tags: typescript, date, tsx

I'm trying to make a dateswitcher, but I'm getting a couple of unwanted "features"

On week 14 (every year) it doesn't select the same day as it was the week before, but instead it stays on the selection from last week (appearing like no date is selected)
For example I select Thursday 31st of March, I switch weeks (so week 14), it's supposed to select Thursday 6th of May, but instead it keeps the selection of 31st of March, because if I go back 31st of March is still selected
This also happens on week 45 (every year)

On week 44 the week suddenly is from Sunday till Saturday instead of Monday till Sunday (like every other week)

And on week 53 (27th December 2021 till 2nd January 2022) it shows 2 Fridays for some reason (Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Fr, Sa)

I added gifs to visualise the problem (sorry if it's hard to see, I can only post gifs)
[image: problem 1]

[image: problem 2]

[image: problem 3]

date-switcher.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { getCurrentWeekNumber, getDaysOfTheWeek } from "../../../../shared/date/dateHelperFunctions";
import { DateSwitcherButton } from "./date-switcher-button"

type DateSwitcherProps = {
  setSelectedDate: (date: Date) => void;
  selectedDate: Date;
}

const milisecondsPerWeek = 604800000;

export const DateSwitcher = ({ setSelectedDate, selectedDate }: DateSwitcherProps) => {
  const [daysOfWeek, setDaysOfWeek] = useState<Date[]>(getDaysOfTheWeek(selectedDate));

  function clickPreviousWeek() {
    const date = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() - milisecondsPerWeek)
    setSelectedDate(date)
  }

  function clickNextWeek() {
    const date = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + milisecondsPerWeek)
    setSelectedDate(date)
    setDaysOfWeek(getDaysOfTheWeek(date))
  }

  return (
    <nav className="bg-white py-2 px-4 rounded-lg flex flex-col space-x-2 justify-center">
      <div className="text-center">
        <h2 className="font-bold text-2xl">{selectedDate.getFullYear()}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between border-black border-2 my-2">
        <button
          className="text-black rounded-full w-8 h-8 flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none"
          onClick={clickPreviousWeek}>&lt;
          <span className="sr-only">Previous week</span>
        </button>
        <div className="font-bold text-xl">Week {getCurrentWeekNumber(selectedDate)}</div>
        <button className="text-black rounded-full w-8 h-8 flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none" onClick={clickNextWeek}>&gt;
          <span className="sr-only">Next week</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="flex space-x-2 justify-center">
        {getDaysOfTheWeek(selectedDate).map((date) => {
          return date
        }).map((date) => (
          <DateSwitcherButton
            key={date.getDate()}
            date={date}
            onPress={() => setSelectedDate(date)}
            selectedDate={selectedDate}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

dateHelperFunctions.ts:

```
export function getCurrentWeekNumber(date: Date): number {
  const firstDayOfYear = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  const milisecondsInADay = 86400000;
  const pastDaysOfYear = (date.valueOf() - firstDayOfYear.valueOf()) / milisecondsInADay;
  return Math.ceil((pastDaysOfYear + firstDayOfYear.getDay()) / 7);
}

export function convertAmsterdamTimezoneToUTC(dateString: string) {
  const date = new Date(dateString);
  date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours() - 2);
  return date.toISOString();
}

export function getFirstDayOfTheWeek(date: Date): Date {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const firstDayOfTheYear = new Date(year, 0, 1);
  const daysToFirstDayOfWeek = (getCurrentWeekNumber(date) - 1) * 7 - firstDayOfTheYear.getDay() + 1;

  return new Date(year, 0, daysToFirstDayOfWeek);
}

export function getDaysOfTheWeek(date: Date): Date[] {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const firstDayOfTheWeek = getFirstDayOfTheWeek(date);
  const daysOfTheWeek: Date[] = [];

  const daysInAWeek = 7;
  const millisecondsInADay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

  console.log("--------------------");
  for (let i = 0; i < daysInAWeek; i++) {
    const date = new Date(firstDayOfTheWeek.getTime() + (i + 1) * millisecondsInADay);
    date.setFullYear(year);
    daysOfTheWeek.push(date);
    console.log(daysOfTheWeek);
    console.log(`week:  + ${date.toDateString()}`);
    console.log(firstDayOfTheWeek.getTime() + (i + 1));
  }
  return daysOfTheWeek;
}
```

date-switcher-button.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useButton } from "@react-aria/button";
import { useFocusRing } from "@react-aria/focus";
import type { AriaButtonProps } from "@react-types/button";

interface NavigationButtonProps extends AriaButtonProps {
  date: Date;
  selectedDate: Date;
}


const week: { [key: number]: string} = {
  1: "Ma",
  2: "Di",
  3: "Wo",
  4: "Do",
  5: "Vr",
  6: "Za",
  0: "Zo",
}

export const DateSwitcherButton = (props: NavigationButtonProps) => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const { buttonProps, isPressed } = useButton(props, ref)
  const { isFocusVisible, focusProps } = useFocusRing(props);

  let label = week[props.date.getDay()]
  let date = props.date.getDate();
  let isSelected = props.selectedDate.getTime() === props.date.getTime();

  useEffect(() => {
    label = week[props.date.getDay()]
    date = props.date.getDate();
    isSelected = props.selectedDate.getTime() === props.date.getTime();
  }, [props.date])

  return (
    <div
      className={`${isPressed ? "bg-teal" : "bg-teal"
      } text-black rounded-full h-12 w-12 flex flex-col items-center justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 ${isFocusVisible ? "ring-blue-300" : ""
      } ${isSelected
        ? "bg-teal border-black border-2"
        : isPressed
          ? "bg-teal"
          : "bg-white"
      }`}
      {...buttonProps}
      {...focusProps}>
      <span className="sr-only">{`${label}: ${date}`}</span>
      <span className="text-lg font-bold">{label}</span>
      <span className="text-sm">{date}</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```